# SSRS Conditional Max

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements, max

I would like my expression to return the max value of a column where another column equals "0".

example :

0 12

0 11

0 7

1 3

1 40

1 1

This should return 12.
I tried several things but can't make it work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like.

```
=MAX(IIF(Fields!ColumnA.Value = 0, Fields!ColumnB.Value, -99999))
```

Column A and B refer to your unnamed columns in your sample data. The -99999 should be a value lower than the lowest Columb B value you will ever get. If Column B is always positive then any negative value or even 0 will suffice here.

The expression reads:
"*for each row, look in Column A. If Column A is zero then return Column B's value, if Column A is not zero, return -99999. Now get the MAX value from these values*"